# GAE deleting blob not working

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have this simple code

```
        BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
        BlobKey blobKeyDelete = new BlobKey(user.getAvatarBlobKey());
        blobstoreService.delete(blobKeyDelete);
```

I'm 100% sure that the value of the key blob is correct and i have no exception. And the blob is not deleted..

I do not know what is wrong, so if you have any idea on how i could troubleshot this that will be great!

Comment: Is it development or production environment issue?

Comment: I cannot test this in dev (i have to figure a way) so it's in production directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a long shot but I had a similar problem, and it turned out that the key was created BEFORE the namespace was set, while the object lived in a namespace. The key contains namespace information. Deleting with a key for a non-existing object does not throw any exception in my experience either.

see this : [Objectify BATCH delete has no effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9495680/objectify-batch-delete-has-no-effect)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using SDK 1.7.0? If so, maybe this is your issue:

http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7785

Comment: Hey Brad, yes i'm using 1.7 but the thing is that i don't have any exceptions :/